# powershell -Scope parameter not found

Tags: powershell

Very strange. I was trying to upgrade [oh-my-posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/) from v2 to v3, the method is documented [here](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/upgrading/). However, when I run command

```
Update-Module -Name oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser
```

Powershell shows

```
Update-Module : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Scope'.
At line:1 char:32
+ Update-Module -Name oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser
+                                ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-Module], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Update-Module
```

I've seen many people using this `-Scope` parameter very often. I don't get why my powershell can't find this parameter.

Using Windows (integrated) Powershell, $PSVersionTable:

```
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1023
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1023
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Can you show the output from `Get-Command Update-Module`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of [`Update-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/powershellget/update-module?view=powershell-5.0) that shipped with Windows PowerShell versions up to v5<sup>[1]</sup> apparently did not have a `-Scope` parameter - see the linked help topic.

The help topic suggests that which scope is targeted is *implied* by whether the PowerShell session is *elevated* (run as admin), in which the `AllUsers` scope is targeted or not, in which case `CurrentUser` is implied.

However, you should be able to update the [`PowerShellGet` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet/2.2.5), which the `Update-Module` cmdlet is a part of, via the PowerShell Gallery, which should give you a `-Scope` parameter thereafter:

```sh
# Run from an ELEVATED session.
# Initial upgrade to the latest version from the PowerShell Gallery.
# Thereafter, use `Update-Module PowerShellGet` for future updates.
# Add -Verbose to see details.
Install-Module -Scope AllUsers PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber
```

<sup>[Phillip Ngan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41410/phillip-ngan) reports that `-AllowClobber` is needed in order to resolve a name conflict.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] I see that your version is v5.1 - yet your `PowerShellGet` module seems to be outdated; conceivably, a manually installed older version is shadowing the bundled one.</sup>

Comment: Strangely though, I do `Uninstall-Module oh-my-posh`, restart PS, do `Install ... -Scope ...` again, it magically works. I have no idea what is happening, but uninstalling seems to solved my problem.

Comment: @Neo, uninstalling and reinstalling sounds like a viable workaround (`Install-Module`, unlike `Update-Module`, always had a `-Scope` parameter, as far as I know), but have you tried upgrading the `PowerShellGet` module?

Comment: No. How do I do that? Maybe `Update-Module PowerShellGet`?

Comment: @Neo, use the command in the answer; initially, to override the bundled version, you  must use `Install-Module -Force`; thereafter, you can use `Update-Module`.

Comment: Thanks, @PhillipNgan - I've added this information to the answer.